# Real analysis Borel measure+Borel set

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on a metric space X. Suppose A is a Borel subset of a proper open subset G of X. Set
       $$A_n=\left\lbrace x\in A: dist(x,X\backslash G)\geq \frac{1}{n} \right \rbrace \: \mathrm{and} \: B_{n}=A_{n+1}-A_{n}.$$

(a) Prove that $\mu(A)\leq \mu(A_{n})+\displaystyle \sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\mu(B_{k})$, without assuming the convergence of the series.

(b) Prove that $\mu(A)=\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\mu(A_{n})$

What I have done: For part (b), it is easy to see that the sequence $(A_{n})$ is increasing, so applying the property of measure, we get that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_{n})=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)$. If one can show that $\mu\left(\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)=A$, then we're done. Any help in showing this is very appreciated.

For part (a) I am thinking that the complement of $A_{n}$ which is the set of all
x in A such that $dist(x,X\backslash G)<\frac{1}{n}$ has measure zero. Hence, A can be written as $A=A_{n}\cup B_{n}\cup B_{n+1}\cup B_{n+2}\cup.....$ and there from there get the inequality. However, I am not still fully convinced with this approach and anyhelp with that is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why aren't you fully satisfied with your approach to (a)? For (b), just show that for each $x\in A$, except possibly on a set of measure 0, there exists an $N>0$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $x\in \cup_{k=1}^n A_k$.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to show $$ \mu \left( \cup_{n=1}^\infty A_n \right) = \mu (A)? $$

Comment: Can you check that for $x \in X$, $\operatorname{dist}(x, G^c) > 0$ if and only if $x \in G$? This immediately yields $$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n = A_n \sqcup \bigsqcup_{k=n}^{\infty} B_k. $$ Then by the countable additivity of $\mu$ we have $$\mu(A) = \mu(A_n) + \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \mu(B_k) $$ and by the continuity from below, $$\mu(A) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n). $$

Comment: Thanks Adrian for editing and correcting the problem!

Comment: Alex, how to show that the complement of $A_{n}$ has measure 0? thanks!